# Paypal REST Api returning internal service error

Tags: php, curl, paypal

Im currently making paypal live on a website and am now at the executing payment part. Which is returning a 'Internal Service Error' This was working about 30 minutes ago but now has stopped.

Heres my code

> > $ch = curl_init();
>
> $data = '{"payer_id": "'.$payerid.'"}'; curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,
>   "https://api.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment/".$payref."/execute/");
>
> > ```
> >             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
> >             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data); 
> >             curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
> >             'Content-Type:application/json',
> >             "Authorization: Bearer " . $access_token)
> >             );
> >
> >             $resultCurl = curl_exec($ch);
> > ```

Can anybody tell me if theres anything wrong with this?

Comment: Do you have a debug id from the curl response?

Comment: Yes its 880721fddfa06. Not sure what I can do with the debug ID though.